# Cant remove all instances of a specific class

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

Using a delegate method im creating a instance of a class named mv, i want to have a clear button that removes all instances of it.

So I decided to add them to a mutableArray:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mvArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
```

the method:

```
-(void)addItemViewController:(VCDecorations *)controller didChooseImage:(UIImage *)image    
{
    if (image) {
        self.imageDecoration = image;
        mv = [[MovableImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
        [mvArray arrayByAddingObject:mv];
         NSLog(@"%@",mvArray);
         NSLog(@"%d",(integer_t)mvArray.count);   
        [self.view addSubview:mv];
    }
```

and

```
- (IBAction)doClearBtn:(id)sender {
    [mvArray removeAllObjects];
}
```

But it seems that the instance isn't added. the log is:

```
2013-10-18 16:06:38.149 manning1[13498:a0b] 0 
2013-10-18 16:06:42.105 manning1[13498:a0b] ( ) 
2013-10-18 16:06:42.106 manning1[13498:a0b] 0
2013-10-18 16:06:45.341 manning1[13498:a0b] ( )
```

Comment: Are you sure your view is loaded? Because you init your array in the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid making array which has 0 capacity

```
mvArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
```

Use that for example:

```
mvArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

The main problem is that you should use this method to add object to your array:

```
[mvArray addObject:mv];
```

[mvArray arrayByAddingObject:mv]; - that returns new array so you will have to use it like:
mvArray = [mvArray arrayByAddingObject:mv]; - but it doesn't make sense to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `[mvArray arrayByAddingObject:mv];` with `[mvArray addObject:mv];`

`arrayByAddingObject:` returns a new array, which you're ignoring.